# Java DOM: cannot write adapted XML to file

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have the following simplified XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExportData>
<Rows>
    <R>
        <companyCodestringtrue>101</companyCodestringtrue>
        <transactionQualifierstring>Sales</transactionQualifierstring>
        <menuItemNumberlong>4302150</menuItemNumberlong>
        <productQuantityinttrue>14</productQuantityinttrue>
        <productValueInclVATdecimaltrue>1.90</productValueInclVATdecimaltrue>
        <productValueExclVATdecimaltrue>1.775701</productValueExclVATdecimaltrue>
    </R>
    <R>
        <companyCodestringtrue>101</companyCodestringtrue>
        <transactionQualifierstring>Sales</transactionQualifierstring>
        <menuItemNumberlong>333555</menuItemNumberlong>
        <productQuantityinttrue>0</productQuantityinttrue>
        <productValueInclVATdecimaltrue>3.90</productValueInclVATdecimaltrue>
        <productValueExclVATdecimaltrue>3.775701</productValueExclVATdecimaltrue>
    </R>
    <R>
        <companyCodestringtrue>101</companyCodestringtrue>
        <transactionQualifierstring>Sales</transactionQualifierstring>
        <menuItemNumberlong>1235665</menuItemNumberlong>
        <productQuantityinttrue>5</productQuantityinttrue>
        <productValueInclVATdecimaltrue>4.90</productValueInclVATdecimaltrue>
        <productValueExclVATdecimaltrue>4.775701</productValueExclVATdecimaltrue>
    </R>
</Rows>
</ExportData>
```

I need to delete each complete `<R>` element if the `<productQuantityinttrue>` element equals "0".

I came up with the following Java code:

```
package filterPositions;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class FilterPositions {

public static String result = "";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        File filePath = new File("C:/LSA_SALES_EXPORT_1507_test_zero_qu.xml");
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filePath);

        Node rootNode = doc.getDocumentElement();
        final Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();

        // output new XML Document
        DocumentBuilder parser = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document newdoc = parser.newDocument();
        newdoc.adoptNode(traversingXML(element));

        writeXmlFile(newdoc, "LSA_SALES_EXPORT_1507_test_zero_qu_OUT.xml");
        System.out.println("Done...");
        System.out.println("Exiting...");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Element traversingXML(Element element) {
    NodeList positionen = element.getElementsByTagName("R");
    Element e = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < positionen.getLength(); i++) {
        e = (Element) positionen.item(i);
        for (Node child = e.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()) {
            if (child instanceof Element && "productQuantityinttrue".equals(child.getNodeName())&& "0".equals(child.getTextContent())) {
                e.getParentNode().removeChild(e);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(e);
    return e;
}

public static void writeXmlFile(Document doc, String filename) {
    try {
        // Prepare the DOM document for writing
        Source source = new DOMSource();

        // Prepare the output file
        File file = new File(filename);
        Result result = new StreamResult(file);

        // Write the DOM document to the file
        Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                .newTransformer();
        xformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
    }
}

}
```

I am not sure if my method "traversingXML" is working properly. My problem right now is that the adapted XML structure (one  deleted) is not written to `newdoc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't copy the original document to `newdoc`; instead you create a new, empty XML document.

Instead, try this code:

```
 ...
 final Element element = doc.getDocumentElement(); // original code up to here

 traversingXML(element); // delete the node

 writeXmlFile(doc, "LSA_SALES_EXPORT_1507_test_zero_qu_OUT.xml"); // save modified document
```

Comment: Hello Aaron, it is not working. Even if I do //traversingXML(element); the target XML is empty. I thought it would just write the source to the target. Have you got any other ideas? Best regards, Peter PS: in Eclipse debugging it seems the source XML is never read!?

Comment: I found one mistake in my "writeXMLFile" method: `Source source = new DOMSource(doc);`

Comment: If `doc` is empty, then everything else will fail. If `docBuilder.parse(filePath);` fails, it should throw an exception. How do you know the source XML is never read? Did you have a look at `doc` in the debugger? What value has the field `rootElement`?

Comment: Hello Aaron, yes my error was in "writeXMLFile" method: `Source source = new DOMSource(doc);` Thank you for your hint though - it would have not worked without your help.